# How to open select mock location app in developer option android?

Tags: android, android-security, android-settings

I want to make user to redirect to developer option-> mock location when it has been enabled. My requirement is, when there is any fake gps location tracked, I need to redirect to developer option-> Select mock location app to disable.

```
 if (AppUtils.isMockLocationEnabled(mLastLocation, FeedbackActivity.this)) {
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(FeedbackActivity.this);
                                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_response_accepted1);

                                    Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
                                    TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.response);
                                    textView.setText("Turn off Fake Gps");

                                    Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Cancel_button);

                                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                                    dialog.show();

                                    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {

//    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));

             //I tried this but this is not working..
                                            Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), "mock_location");
                                        }
                                    });
}
```

I tried this "mock_location" but it's not going to select mock location app. nothing is performing..

//this below is just opening only developer option. How to redirect to mock location in developer settings to turn off?

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```